# When something is good / not good for someone to be done

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Please imagine someone's parents are giving some advice to their son. The father wants to say something that feels it would be very beneficial for his son. (For instance: continue his education.) 
Which one of the sentences below would work in natural English:

> **1)** Do it; it is to your **profit**. 
>   **2)** Do it; it is to your **benefit**. 
>   **3)** Do it; it is to your **own good**.

**Added:** What the son would say in reply when he thinks contrary to his father?

> 1) It has no **profit** for me. 
>   2) It has no **benefit** for me. 
>   3) It is not in **my own good**.

I wonder if you could let me know about a better option, if you think that there is something wrong with my made-up sentences and if you think that there is a better/more common alternative in natural English that can make a better sense.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I usually hear, "... for your own good."  or "... for your own sake" As a reply, I hear, "... won't do me good", but it all depends on the mood. Sarcastic response would be "Are you sure?"

Comment: although I would say that 'for your own good' is usually for something they have no choice in doing (like taking medicine they don't like the taste of) and their parents may be 'coercing' them to do.

Comment: Well @Smock what would you say instead in my both cases?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently had a similar conversation with my daughter. I told her things like "You will regret it later if you don't" and "This will really help you down the road" and "All of the best jobs require a college degree".

But I agree with @Smock about using "It's for your own good". That's really only used when you have control and are forcing someone to do something.

The son might respond with "It won't benefit me" or "I don't need it" or even "I don't want to".

Comment: Thank you, @Mik. You mentioned: **It's for your own good". That's really "only" used when you have control and are forcing someone to do something.** But isn't it a matter of intonation or one's tone of speech?Aside from the fact that the meaning of many even sarcastic sentences can be changed having a specific intonation and tone, the sentence does not sound that forceful to me. I wonder if you could tell me more about it.

Comment: The sentence isn’t really meant to sound forceful.  It tends to be said to try to placate the person you’re forcing.  I can’t think of an intonation that would change that, off the top of my head.  It could be said sarcastically, like if the son were complaining to a friend about being forced.  The friend could respond with that phrase sarcastically as a way to mock the parents.